# How to access SQL Server database in one host from informatica pc in another box

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I installed informatica PC8.6 on Windows XP and SQL Server 2008 R2 on another machine. How can I access this database from informatica pc.8.6. and is it possible to access?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. First install SQL Server Management Studio on the first machine and try to establish a connection to the database. If it works, you will be able to use the same address and credentials in PowerCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to access SQL server from  Informatica. Just using the same sql user ( not windows user ) to log in to SQL server. Make sure that you can connect to sql server from remote machine in your case

Comment: thanks for your reply..and one more can i access oracle data base from same info client?this oracle database is installed in 64 bit machine

Comment: Yes. Infomatica is built to connect to many different database. So, basically, you can connect to oracle or any server which Infomatica support.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any database from any server if you have the driver installed on the the client.

If the client os supports the database, you can get the client installed there.  If not, you can always get the cess channel through ODBC.